# Why in Angular there is a big difference between importing global css files in main component css file instead of importing them in styles.css

Tags: angular

I'm trying to reduce the size of my global css files(bootstrap...etc) which I use in my Angular project and I found that if I import them in the app main component css file and set view encapsulation to none, the size of styles.js file is a lot smaller than if I import the same styles in styles.css. Why this is happening?